# camel jetty:http and post data

Tags: jetty, apache-camel

I need to receive some data from an URL every 30 seconds.

I wanted to use camel and jetty:http for it. I found one problem - to get the data from URL i need to send post variables with login and password.

How to do this?

I've been looking for an example, but i didn't found anything.

Could you help me?

And additionally question:

if i want to make some action for every 30 seconds, my code should looks like this?

```
from("file:src/data?noop=true&delay=30000")   
.to("file:src/new");
```

thanks for help

Comment: should be separate questions...

Comment: see [camel-http4](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html) and [camel-timer](http://camel.apache.org/timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you want post data through http component, you can using form_urlencoded content type:

```
from("direct:postTest")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED))
            .setBody(simple("text=a&user=ethan"))
            .to("http://someurl");
```